# how to set values in sublist subrecord? (SuiteScript 1.0)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to set `quantity` field value in my sublist and `quantity` in my sublist subrecord(inventorydetail). When I try to `.editLineItemSubrecord()`, system throws an error:

```
"code\":\"CANNOT_EDIT_SUBRECORD\",\"details\":\"Cannot edit this subrecord, it is either in readonly state or dead state.\"
```

My code is as follows:

```
 function updateRec(matRecArr, request, qtySetByUser, itemToFind) {
  var tranOrderRec = nlapiLoadRecord('transferorder', matRecArr)
  var count = tranOrderRec.getLineItemCount('item');

  for (var i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {
    var indx = tranOrderRec.findLineItemValue('item', 'item', itemToFind);

    if (indx > -1) {
      tranOrderRec.selectLineItem('item', indx);
      tranOrderRec.setCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity', qtySetByUser);
      var subrecord = tranOrderRec.editLineItemSubrecord('item', 'inventorydetail', 1);
      subrecord.selectLineItem('inventoryassignment', 1);
      subrecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', qtySetByUser);
      subrecord.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
      subrecord.commit();
    }
    tranOrderRec.commitLineItem('item');
    tranOrderRec.commit();
  }
  nlapiSubmitRecord(tranOrderRec, true, true);
  nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'MATERIAL REC. UPDATED!', tranOrderRec);
}
```

can anyone tell me the mistake I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

Refer "Editing an Address Subrecord on an Existing Customer Record" in help or suite answers